# How to setup default start up applications in IBM websphere?

Tags: websphere

Whenever I restart my websphere application server by default it starts all the applications deployed. How can I make only particular applications will get start in the start up?

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise Applications > Your Application > Target specific application status

Enable Auto Start/Disable Auto Start

Comment: Can you please provide the solution for IBM Websphere 6.0.2.25?